# Why to_numpy method converts one int dataframe colum to string column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data frame as below...

```
Age  Sex  CP TrestBPS Cholesteral  Sugar  ECG Heart rate  Exercise  
58    1   2      150         270      1    1        111         0  

Oldpeak  Slope Nb Vessel  CA  Thal  
0.8      2         0      3     1
```

In this column values (Nb Vessel) is integer.
I need to convert it to array.
I am using to_numpy method. But it makes this column values to string as shown below.

`[[58 1 2 ... '0' 3 1] [48 1 2 ... '0' 3 1] [46 1 3 ... '0' 2 1] ... [62 1 0 ... '1' 3 1] [44 1 2 ... '1' 2 1] [59 1 1 ... '0' 2 1]]`

I also tried by providing dtype as float32 but it wont fix the issue.

Can you please help to fix this issue?
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the dataframe's `dtypes`?  I suspect `Vessel` is `object` containing strings   pandas does not quote strings so you can't tell from the display whether it's a number or a character.

Comment: You are correct. I checked that, it seems it is string in dataframe it self. I need to convert it in DF.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @hpaulj 's question into account, you will have to convert the `"Nb Vessel"` column in your DataFrame from `object` to `int`. You could do this by:

```
df = df.astype({'Nb Vessel': 'int32'})
```

Then you can convert that to a numpy array using `to_numpy()`:

```
np_arr = df.to_numpy()
```

The resulting values in the numpy array should be of type int.